# Can't find built-in types and namespaces

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2019

I loaded up an old `UWP` project and now it gives me a zillion errors like this one:

> CS0518 Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported

I get red squiggles in `Visual Studio` anywhere the `System` namespace is referenced.

I tried `dotnet restore`, but that didn't help. What can I do to fix this `UWP` project?

Comment: @Codexer it's not necessary to put terms such as UWP and Visual Studio in code tags; I asked about this once before on meta and that was the overwhelming consensus...

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I figured it out - I needed to:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete my `bin` and `obj` folders
3. Reopen Visual Studio